# Outsource MUI Styling in separate files in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i try to outsource the modification of the mui styling in seperate files, but the problem is that *.module.css dont work when i using "className={styles.h6}" instead of "variant="h6".

Here a example that i tried to modify:

```
const Void: React.FC<VoidProps> = ({name}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6">
        <BlockIcon />
        {name}
      </Typography>
    </>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to write MUI sx in css files? Or is there a other solution, in which the styling is not written in the component itself?

Do somebody know a solution to that? I have the requirement to put styling like css, sx und others outside of the component files. Is this even possible with MUI?

Thank you for your help.

Edit/Solution:

It works now with module.css like in this case:

```
Void.tsx:

import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import styles from "./cssModules/Void.module.css"
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import BlockIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Block";



/**
 * @module Void
 *
 * Displays a void element with a block icon and a name.
 *
 * @param {string} name - Name of the void element
 * @returns {JSX.Element} - Void component
 */

type VoidProps = {
  name: string;
};

const Void: React.FC<VoidProps> = ({name}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Typography className={clsx(styles.Typography)}>
        <BlockIcon />
        {name}
      </Typography>
    </>
  );
};

export default Void;



Void.module.css:

.Typography {
  color: rgb(255, 47, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(218, 143, 14), rgb(217, 255, 0)) padding-box,
  linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(204, 50, 50)) border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50em !important;
  width: 4.7em; 
  max-width: 22em;
  font-size: 1.9em !important;
}
```

Thank you for helping Victor L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's possible. `clsx` library helps you combine multiple class names into one string.

```
/* style.css */
.red {
  color: red;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* App.js */

import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import clsx from "clsx";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return <Typography className={clsx("red", "bold")}>Hello, world!</Typography>;
}
```

And I think the problem ("`*.module.css` don't work when I'm using `className={styles.h6}` instead of `variant="h6"`") is caused by your CSS file.

In my opinion, of course, I can't see your CSS file, but I can guess:

```
h6 {
  color: red;
}
```

Maybe you have defined like this.
But if you use this in `className` prop, you need to define CSS like this:

```
.h6 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: If my answer is incorrect, feel free to ask me.

Comment: The direction was right. I had to make some adjustments. But i cant modify the font size and i dont know why.